# joomla popup that should close only by click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, popup

I am using popup anywhere plugin in joomla. I have to display article page detail on that popup at time of user log in. But here popup close on click out side of popup screen also, i dont want this. Popup should only close at time of clicking "Agree" button that article have.

Please let me know if you have any other plugins or ideas.

Comment: Please show some code from the plugin that currently triggers the close event else it's hard to answer this. Adam has provided an answer that will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This should prevent the window from being closed by clicking away from the element:

```
$('#your-close-button').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: May be it is not a good idea, because it will affect to other place also in joomla. Is there other plugin as per my need?

Comment: Don't really understand what you need? If you're comfortable to edit the code you can just add the above in to wherever you need it. I'm not really familiar with a great deal of Joomla plugins so can't give any further advice on that.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has a modal window as part of its core code, which is based on the mootools Squeezebox.  You can call up an iframe in a modal window which cannot close like this:

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.mootools'); ?>
<a href="http://www.example.com/page2.html" class="modal" 
   rel="{closable: false, handler:'iframe'}">
   Click here to launch a popup</a>
```

If you then want page2.html to have a close button, you should add this script to the parent window,

```
<script>               
function closepopup() {
SqueezeBox.close();              
}        
</script>
```

and create the button like this:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.closepopup()">CLOSE!</a>
```